# Edit the styling of a button (PHP & MySQL used to populate it) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Good day,

I am building an e-commerce site.

I have used MySQL for the back-end database and PHP to populate the data and tables into my Website.

I have managed a way that when a product is succesfully sold that the innerText of that button (that leads to it's detailed page) changes from "View" to "SOLD".

I now want to use JavaScript to scan through the table and Find all the button that contain the word "SOLD" and change the styling of them.

*I think my main problem is that the data is puled through from the MySQL database and isn't 'fixed' into the HTML, which is why I think my code is not working.

Here are snippets of my relevant code:
This is the "button" that I want to change, if required condition is met.

```
<td id="view_button"><?php echo "<a id='isSold' href='/dynamic_page.php?id={$row['id']}'>{$row['View']}</a>"; ?></td>
```

Here is my attempt at the JavaScript:

```
const isSold = document.getElementById('isSold');

function ToggleSold(){
  if(isSold.innerHTML === "SOLD"){
    this.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  } else {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
}
```

Please bare with me, I taught myself how to code over the last 6 months.
All help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you have multiple buttons on the same page? If that's the case, then the issue is that they all will have the same id. Id's in HTML _must_ be unique within the document. This could be solved by using a class instead and then search for that.

Comment: `this.style.backgroundColor` should probably be `isSold.style.backgroundColor`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I have tried to change the JS to isSold.style.backgroundColor But that dosen't seem to work.

Yes all the button will have that id, thats why I thought an IF statement would be able to identify the buttons that have the innerText changed to "SOLD" and then only edit those ones?
I can try changing it to a class and using 'quesrySelector'?

Comment: Does the button text get changed dynamically on the client side? If not, then why would you want to do this in JavaScript to begin with, do it in PHP already then.

Comment: @CBroe, good point! Let me look into it.

Comment: Something like `echo "<a class='".($row['View'] == 'SOLD' ? 'sold' : '')."' href=...` should do the job. That should give all links to sold items the class `sold`, so you can apply formatting via that class from your stylesheet. (That is generally preferable, to directly setting inline styles.)

Answer (score 0):

I took the advice of the above comment to use PHP instead of JavaScript.
It has done the trick.

I'll post the code here, in case someone has the same issue:

```
<td id="view_button">
    <a style="<?php if ($row['View'] == 'SOLD') {
        echo 'color:rgb(128, 128, 128);
              background: rgb(217, 217, 217);
              border: 2px solid rgb(128, 128, 128);
              font-size: 10px';

    } else if($row['View'] == 'View') {
        ;
    } ?>" href="<?php if($row['View'] == 'SOLD') {
        echo '';
    } else if($row['View'] == 'View') {
        echo "/dynamic_page.php?id={$row['id']}";
    } ?>">
        <?php echo $row['View'] ?>
    </a>
</td>
```